# How can I easily link sources for dependencies in Grails project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Is there any way to get IDEA to automatically download sources for Grails, my plugins and all the dependencies? Alternately, is there an easy way to get IDEA to pickup sources downloaded by this plugin?

http://www.grails.org/plugin/eclipse-scripts

It puts them under ~/.ivy2/...

Answer (score 1):

IDEA should automatically load all plugins for a Grails project, if the `Grails/Griffon` plugin is being used.

I see all the Grails plugins for a given project in my *Grails View*, under *Plugins*.

If you aren't seeing the files, try right-clicking on the project's name in the Grails View, and choosing `Grails > Synchronize Grails settings`.

Please note that if you are using the free (community) version of IntelliJ IDEA, it does **not** include the necessary plugins for working with Grails directly.  You must pay for the full version to get it.